# Change euro to dollar on mac

Tags: mac, remapping

When coding in vi/vim/mac-vim inputting `$` brings you to the end of the line. `$` is achieved by pressing <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd> on a US keyboard.

However on my European keyboard, I have to press <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd> to get `$` which is more difficult to reach :)

Is there some setting to get `$` instead of `€` when pressing <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd> on a European keyboard? If not, is there some cleaver way of remapping?

KeyRemap4MacBook only seems to have the € to $ option for French keyboards.

Thanks!

Comment: You can add `<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEY_4, VK_SHIFT, KeyCode::KEY_4, ModifierFlag::OPTION_L</autogen>` to [private.xml](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en).

Comment: perfect Lauri Ranta!